# How to center an image in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, layout, react-native-stylesheet, react-native-flexbox

###### Background

I have an image meant to be displayed while other content is loading. 
I want it to be centered and look the same on all devices.

###### Problem

Currently, the image shows up at the top left. 
I would like it to be centered – horizontally and vertically.

###### Question

What is the solution to make the image centered and have the right size?

---

The height of my image is 776 px, and the width is 600 px.
I know I need to set the image size in the style sheet.
From my understanding, I can use [JSX](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) to do this.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Image, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';

const logoImage = require('../assets/images/logo.jpg');

const LoadingScreen = () => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Image style={styles.logo} source={logoImage} />
  </View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
  },
  logo: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: 300,
    height: 400,
  },
});

export default LoadingScreen;
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You need to set the style of `<View>` for `justifyContent` and `alignItems` for centering the `<Image>`.

Should be like this :

```
const LoadingScreen = () => (
<View style={styles.container}>
    <Image
        style={styles.logo}
        source={logo}
    />
</View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  logo: {
    width: 300,
    height: 400,
  },
});
```

Or you can use `alignSelf` on the `<Image>` to make it center, but it will still need to add `justifyContent` on `<View>` to make it center vertically.

Answer (score 20):

The View container should have styling as

```
flexDirection: 'column'
justifyContent: 'center'
alignItems: 'center'
height: '100%'
```

The height makes sure it spans throughout the page, thus making the image become both vertically and horizontally aligned.

For the image size, I think using percentage will do the trick instead of defining definite width/height.

Comment: I got it working like this, do you think this is good for all devices? const LoadingScreen = () => (
    <View
        style={styles.container}
    >
        <Image
            style={styles.logo}
            source={logo}
        />
    </View>
);
 
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        display: 'flex',
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
 
    },
    logo: {
        width: 220,
        height: 300,
        marginTop: -50,
    },
});

Answer (score 9):

Set in view:

```
justifycontent:center
```

And in child:

```
alignself:center
```

And perform in task.

Answer (score 6):

Set in parent view:

```
justifycontent:center
```

And in child set:

```
alignself:center
```

Answer (score 0):

> ###### *What is the solution to make the image centered and have the right size?*

[The documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox?language=javascript) for using Flexbox in React Native tells us why your attempt failed.

###### [Justify content](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox?language=javascript#justify-content)

`justifyContent` describes how to align *children* within the main axis of their container 
(which by default is *column-wise* for React Native).

###### [Align items](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox?language=javascript#align-items)

`alignItems` describes how to align *children* along the cross axis of their container.

Thus, setting `alignItems` and `justifyContent` on the `<Image />` element affects the position of the *children* of the image. 
But in your case, `<Image />` doesn't have any children, so the effect is nil.

#### How to make your code work as intended

To style the image, we need to set `alignItems` and `justifyContent` for the *parent* of the image, which in your case is the `<View />` element. 
Assuming that `<View />` is styled by `container` (and `<Image />` by `logo`), the following style sheet settings will center the image in both directions. <sup>1</sup>

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Image, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';

const logoImage = { uri: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/15jTl.png' };

export default function LoadingScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image style={styles.logo} source={logoImage} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  logo: {
    width: 280,
    height: 260,
  },
});
```

[image: The image is centered horizontally and vertically.]

#### An alternative solution

###### [Align self](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox?language=javascript#align-self)

`alignSelf` has the same options and effect as `alignItems` but instead of affecting the children within a container, you can apply this property to a single element.

Just set `alignSelf` on the image itself, instead of setting `alignItems` on its parent.

This method can be handy if the image should be centered, while there is text below the image that should be left-aligned.

Consider the example below. 
In portrait mode, all content fits on the screen, and is centered horizontally and vertically. 
In landscape mode, the image + text doesn't fit vertically.
The whole image should be displayed when scrolling to the top, while all text should be displayed when scrolling to the bottom. <sup>2</sup>

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Image, ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

const logoImage = { uri: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/15jTl.png' };

export default function LoadingScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollView}>
        <Image style={styles.logo} source={logoImage} />
        <Text>Here are some</Text>
        <Text>lines of text</Text>
        <Text>below the image.</Text>
        <Text> - - -</Text>
        <Text>I want the image</Text>
        <Text>to be centered,</Text>
        <Text>but this text</Text>
        <Text>to be left-aligned,</Text>
        <Text>not centered.</Text>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { flex: 1, padding: 8 },
  scrollView: { flexGrow: 1, justifyContent: 'center' },
  logo: { alignSelf: 'center', width: 280, height: 260 },
});
```

[image: All text should be displayed when scrolling to the bottom.]

---

<sup>1</sup>
The `flex: 1` clause makes `container` span the whole screen height instead of just the image height.

<sup>2</sup>
To reproduce: [download](https://github.com/henk9/Henke/raw/main/StackOverflow-Q45685176/45685176.zip) and unzip to some directory of your choice. 
Switch to that directory and run `npm install` and then `npm start`. 
(You'll also need an emulator or a physical device to run the application.)

Comment: My answer here also covers 
[vertical centering when using ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32664397).