# Image not centered in react native

Tags: android, react-native

I have a file logo.js that goes as:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Image } from 'react-native'

const logo = () => (
   <Image source = {{uri:'url_of_image'}}
   style={{ width: 100, height: 100,justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}
   />
)
export default logo
```

I'm using this file in App.js as:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.js'

const App = () => {
   return (
      <logo />
   )
}
export default App
```

I have two questions.

1. My image is appearing in the top-left section, while I want it to appear in the center of screen (both horizontally as well as vertically). Why aren't `justifyContent` and `alignItems` doing that? What do I need to do to fix this issue?
2. My image currently is only 100 pixel by 100 pixel. I want it to appear exactly as its actual size or say 300*300, whichever is smaller. How can I achieve this? Thanks...

**EDIT**

I changed my logo.js to:

```
...
const logo = () => (
   <View style={styles.container}>
   <Image source = {{uri:'url_of_image'}}
   // style={{resizeMode: 'center'}}
   //gives same result with above line comment/uncomment
    />
   </View>
)

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
     flex: 1,
     justifyContent: 'center',
     alignItems: 'center'
   }
 });
```

By this, I am getting a completely blank screen.

I also tried, after going through the duplicate question, this:

```
...
const logo = () => (
   <View style={styles.container}>
   <Image source = {{uri:'url_of_image'}}
   style={styles.logo}
   />
   </View>
)

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
     flex: 1,
     justifyContent: 'center',
     alignItems: 'center',
   },
   logo: {
     width: 300,
     height: 300,
   },
 });
```

I know I have hardcoded height and width, but I was just focusing on centering it. It centres my Image exactly as I want. So thanks for mentioning that link. But, I'm still unable to do that 300 vs itself thing. Please help me figure that out...

Comment: Just remove the hard coded `width` and `height`, and use flex . `style={{  justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}`

Comment: @KrishnaSharma using `flix` will spread it to the entire screen

Comment: @KrishnaSharma it won't work

Comment: then don't pass any width and height, also wrap your Image view inside any container

Comment: @KrishnaSharma not passing height and width gives black screen

Comment: Wrap `logo` in a `View`. Add `{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }` to the View. Remove `justifyContent` and `alignItems` from Image.

Comment: Use `{alignSelf:'center'}` property in your image style. For showing actual size use `{resizeMode: 'center'}` property in your image style

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Center Image React Native Loading Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45685176/center-image-react-native-loading-screen)

Comment: @ravibagul91 See edit. Thanks for this link, was really helpful

Comment: @Dan thanks for this suggestion. It was helpful. Can you please help me fix the image size issue too?

Comment: @FatimaSiddique please see edit. It does not fix my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get image size by using `Image.getSize`

Here is a sample code,

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Image,
} from 'react-native';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { 
      width: 300,
      height: 300,
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    Image.getSize('https://facebook.github.io/react/logo-og.png', (width, height) => { 
      if (width < 300) this.setState({ width })
      if (height < 300) this.setState({ height })
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Image source = {{uri:'https://facebook.github.io/react/logo-og.png'}}
        style={{ width: this.state.width, height: this.state.height, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is amazing. Works perfectly. Thanks a lot.